# What is the difference between a joint distribution function and the joint density function.

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I am working on a problem which asks me to find the joint distribution function for the random variable X,Y of a previous problem. In the previous problem I can find the joint density function

f(x,y)=xy/96  for x between 0 and 4, and y between 1 and 5.
0 otherwise

I cant find what is the difference between those two.... Do they mean the cumulative distribution function?
I am studying on my own so there’s nobody I can ask.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, they do mean the CDF $F(x,y)=\int^x_{-\infty}\int^y_{-\infty}f_{X,Y}(u,v)dvdu$.

Comment: Thank you, if learning alone sometimes small problems can be stumble stones

Comment: Glad to help. Then about a week ago you found a nice place to fill up the gaps :-). Good luck with your study.